# ggplot combined stat_smooth for some factor levels in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

My data has 3 factor levels, each with an x and y coordinate. I'm using ggplot to create a scatter plot, to which I'd like to add a smooth. However, I want the smooth only to use 2 of the 3 factor levels. The result should be a single fit of the data points in those 2 factor levels, but with all 3 levels scattered.

Example:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(x=rnorm(300), y=rnorm(300), f=rep(c("a","b","c"), 100))

ggplot(data, aes(x,y,color=f)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method="gam", formula=y~s(x), se=F)

ggplot(data[data$f %in% c("a","b"),], aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=f)) +
  stat_smooth(method="gam", formula=y~s(x), se=F)
```

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the first image has smooths for all factors individually. The second combines data from factor levels "a" and "b", but that's because I've removed "c" from the data.

How can I retain the scatterplot from the first image and overlay the smooth fit from the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stat_smooth` has a `data` argument, which you can use to build a subset:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x,y,color=f)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(data=subset(data, f!="c"), 
              inherit.aes=F, aes(x, y),
              method="gam", formula=y~s(x), 
              se=F)
```

In addition, you can use `inherit.aes=FALSE` to change the aesthetics mapping.

Comment: Excellent. Just what I was looking for. Thank you.